# Afetando divs em javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho duas `div` com `#bodyProduct`, e dentro de cada uma tem uma `div` com uma `div` com um `#btn-extende`.

A `div` pai *product* tem um `height` fixo com *overflow*, ocultando o restante do conteúdo da mesma e o botão `extende` serve justamente pra estender essa `div` pra um `height` auto, para mostrar todo o conteúdo, mas o problema é que quando eu coloco o sistema pra funcionar clicando no primeiro `btn-extende`, dá certo, mas quando eu clico no segundo `btn`, ele ao invés de estender a `div` ao qual ele está inserido, ele estende a primeira `div` com o `#bodyProduct`.

Como faço para afetar somente a `div` pai do `btn` que for apertado?

```
<div id="bodyProduct">
     <div id="btn-extende">

     </div>
</div>

<div id="bodyProduct">
     <div id="btn-extende">

     </div>
</div>



<style>
      #bodyProduct{
        position: relative;
        width: 960px;
        height: 295px;
        margin: 20px 60px;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      #btn-extende{
        z-index: 9999;
        position: absolute;
        width: 35px;
        height: 18px;
        background-color: #555;
        bottom: 6px;
        right: 6px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
</style>

$('btn-extende').on('click', function(){
     $('#bodyProduct').css('height', 'auto');
 });
```

Comment: A propriedade `id` deve ser única na página. Não podem existir mais de um elemento com o mesmo `id`; o navegador só considerará o primeiro e ignorará o restante.

Answer (score 1):

Só utilize `id` para um único elemento na página. Para uma lista de elementos repetidos que terão os mesmos estilos, use `class`.

Transforme as `id`s `#bodyProduct` e `#btn-extende` em classes: `.bodyProduct` e `.btn-extende`. Além de ser a forma correta, não acarretará nenhum problema de formatação já que todos os elementos com essas classes terão os mesmos estilos.

Como está usando jQuery, use o código abaixo para expandir a `div` ao click no "botão":

```
$('.btn-extende').on('click', function(){
   $(this)
   .parent()
   .css('height', 'auto');
});
```

**Veja:**

```js
$('.btn-extende').on('click', function(){
   $(this)
   .parent()
   .css('height', 'auto');
});
```

```css
.bodyProduct{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  /* width: 960px; */
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px 60px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-extende{
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #555;
  bottom: 6px;
  right: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bodyProduct">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   <div class="btn-extende">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="bodyProduct">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   <div class="btn-extende">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma coisa que percebi é que quando se usa o ***id*** para buscar sua referência no JavaScript, o jQuery *-ou o próprio navegador-* trata apenas um único elemento, ou seja, o primeiro com aquele ***id*** específico.

Para resolver essa questão eu utilizei o atributo ***class*** nos botões, para que os dois sejam reconhecidos pelo script.

Ao invés de procurar o elemento "pai" pelo ***id*** dentro do evento ***click*** (o que encontraria o primeiro elemento mesmo que este estivesse fora), coloquei a referência do elemento pai pelo atributo ***parentNode*** através do objeto do escopo do evento (this).

[Ver no Codepen](https://codepen.io/mathues/pen/WJgabJ)

```js
$('.btn-extende').on('click', function(event){
  var parent = $(this.parentNode)
  
  let height = parent.css('height')
  
  parent.css('height',
    (height === '40px') ? 'auto' : '40px'
  )
 });
```

```css
 #bodyProduct{
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 40px;
   margin: 20px 60px;
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-extende{
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #555;
  bottom: 6px;
  right: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bodyProduct">
  <div class="btn-extende"></div>
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec mi ut odio imperdiet gravida. Mauris vitae pretium velit, at pulvinar ante. Suspendisse eget mollis metus, ut convallis elit. Vestibulum ac purus et lectus rhoncus vulputate. Vivamus ornare efficitur odio in mollis. Quisque suscipit interdum magna, nec feugiat nibh volutpat ut. In id posuere ante. Morbi fermentum, quam ut aliquet elementum, mi metus rhoncus orci, sed tristique urna neque eu diam. Maecenas vehicula mauris eu pulvinar maximus. Donec in nisl velit. Sed vestibulum dui ut finibus aliquet. Fusce pulvinar felis arcu, at suscipit nisi aliquet in. Quisque pharetra nunc sit amet sodales interdum.
</div>

<div id="bodyProduct">
  <div class="btn-extende"></div>
  
  Sed magna ipsum, sagittis vehicula metus et, pharetra rhoncus neque. Vivamus leo libero, rutrum ac egestas vitae, volutpat eu justo. Quisque tempor convallis odio, vel feugiat tellus blandit semper. Etiam non tempus orci, non finibus orci. Vivamus sollicitudin nibh nec orci fermentum condimentum. Suspendisse vel viverra felis, vel placerat ante. Phasellus ornare sagittis sollicitudin. Etiam interdum feugiat ornare. Duis suscipit justo in aliquam porttitor. Morbi ut mi et velit pretium ornare vitae vitae dolor. Donec nibh felis, elementum nec hendrerit id, cursus sed ante. Aenean tempor tempor purus, id consequat nunc commodo sit amet.
</div>
```

Comment: Os seletores de ID trazem sempre o primeiro porque os IDs devem ser únicos, nunca devem se repetir no mesmo documento HTML.